# Issues querying database - works only on my PC

Tags: c#, ms-access, iteration

I wrote some code that should add database response to the List. it works on my PC, but does not work when I deploy my program to another PC.
I pinned down to my method. It stops working when it hits

```
int tot = rs.Fields.Count;
```

Here is my code:

```
        public static List<List<String>> QUERY(String query, String dbPath)
    {   ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection();
        ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();            ADODB.Command cmdSQLData = new ADODB.Command();
        List<List<String>> RETURNME = new List<List<String>>();
        string cnStrOld = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=" + dbPath + ";Uid=;Pwd=;"; //does not work
        string  cnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" + dbPath;
            cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0;
            cn.Open(cnStr);
            cn.CommandTimeout = 0;
            rs.Open(query, cn);
        while (rs.EOF == false) //GET HEADERNAMES, ADD TO LIST
        {
            List<String> A = new List<string>();
            int tot = rs.Fields.Count;// calculating the amount of columns in the RS
            for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++) //iterating through all columns and checking it's name
            {
                A.Add(rs.Fields[i].Name.ToString());
            }
            RETURNME.Add(A);
            break;
        }
        while (rs.EOF == false)//GET DATA, ADD TO LIST
        {
            List<String> B = new List<string>(); //list of Data
            int tot = rs.Fields.Count;// calculating the amount of columns in the RS
            //Now we add query response
            for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++) //iterating through all columns and checking it's name
            {
                B.Add(rs.Fields[i].Value.ToString());
            }
            RETURNME.Add(B);
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
            rs.Close();
            cn.Close();
        return RETURNME;
    }
```

I use relative paths and they are tested OK. I also have my try-catch staements (I removed them from here to shrink the code) and they indicate no errors. Somehow program is capable of entering to "while (rs.EOF == false)" statement, so I assume that records are returned?

Could you please assist?

---

**I ended up with the following solution:**

```
        public static List<List<String>> QUERY_TEST(String query, String dbPath)
    {

        List<List<String>> RETURNME = new List<List<String>>();
        String cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;";
        OleDbDataAdapter Data1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnStr);

        DataSet a = new DataSet();
        Data1.Fill(a);
        DataTable dt = a.Tables[0];

        //Adding column names to the first row on the list
        List<String> B = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataColumn dr in dt.Columns)
        {
            List<String> A = new List<string>();
            B.Add(dr.Caption.ToString());
        }
        RETURNME.Add(B);

        //Adding data to the columns
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            List<String> A = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                A.Add(dr[i].ToString());
            }
            RETURNME.Add(A);
            break;
        }
        return RETURNME;
    }
```

Comment: are you aware that you can get the header names without having to do a List<List<string>> there is a method you can use to get the FieldNames also you can eliminate all of that code by using a OleDBCommand and you should use the ExecuteReader() command I will clean up your example in a min and post it to see what you think

Comment: also on the Server do you know what version of Microsoft.Interop.Access they are using what version of DAO, Microsoft.Office.Core, ADODB...? your machine will work because it probably references the correct GAC'd version of the Microsoft.Interop.Access libs, I had the same issue I am running Windows7 64bit and the target server has Server 2003 this should only make a difference in the DAO usually.. but it's Microsoft Access so anything is possible..

Comment: I will alter your code and send you an easier way of doing what my understanding is that you are wanting to do..

Comment: do you have email or a means we could chat so I could help you clean up your code basically you can do all of what you need with a nested for loop, 1 List<string> object and get at the fields based on the record count I could paste some code in but I am not sure you would understand what I am doing let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this is what you could do.. of course you need to replace certain things with your variable names where necessary

```
public static List<string> QUERY(string query, string dbpath)
{
   string  cnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" + dbPath;
   oleconn = new OleDbConnection(cnStr);
   List<string>lstColumns = null;
   string[] strarryColumnNames = {}; //keep this just like this it's how you can declare dynamic array
   string strCommaDelimColumns = string.Empty;
   OleDbDataReader drdrRecord = null;
   OleDbConnection oleconn = null;

   using(OleDbCommand  olecmd new OleDbCommand(query, cnStr))
   {
        olecmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
        olecmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;  
        oleconn.Open();
        //if you want to get the record count just setup a query with Select (count) as recCnt .... 
        //do the oledrd execute here.. then call oledrdr.Close(); and assign the other query string to another execute reader
        /* basically do something like this and replace what I have with what you need
            var drdrRecordCntReader = olecmd.ExecuteReader();
            oledrdr.Read();
            intRecCount = (int)oledrdr[recCnt];//value returned from the Select Count(*)
            if (intRecCount == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }//if (intRecCount == 0)        
        */
        oledrdr = olecmd.ExecuteReader();
        lstColumns = new List<string>();
        //load the field header contents here 
        for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < oledrdr.FieldCount; intCounter++)
        {
          lstColumns.Add(oledrdr.GetName(intCounter));
        }       
        strarrayColumnNames = lstColumns.ToArray();     
        strCommaDelimColumns = string.Join(",", strarryColumnNames);
        //use the same lstColumns to add the data no need for a second while loop
        //close the reader oledrdr
        //use it again
        try
        {
             //outter loop - Read row record by record 
            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < intRecCount - 1; intCounter++) // figure out how to get record count
            {
               rdrDataReader.Read();
             //inner loop - read each field data within that row
                 for (int intFieldcnt = 0; intFieldcnt < intColumnCnt; intFieldcnt++)
                 {
                    //put your field data value code here
                 }//for (int intFieldcnt = 0; intFieldcnt < intColumnCnt; intFieldcnt++)
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
    }           
}
```

Comment: did it work what I have sent you..? if so please voteUp thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the path is accessible from the remote computer (e.g. on the remote computer or a network share somewhere) and is accessible by the user that the program is running as.

Answer (score 1):

of the issue is in your connection string change or test your connection string using this instead

```
strAccessConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\yourpath\+yourAccessDataBase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=if you have a password put here;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Declare list B before your first while group. Then add the first B item in the first while group within your for loop. Finanlly before exiting the first while group add rs.MoveNext();

Comment: I can't declare B before; I need to create a new object for every row. I have "List<List<String>> RETURNME = new List<List<String>>(); " declared, this is where the object is placed.
In addition, it does not go that far when it enter the first while loop, it is getting stuck on "int tot = rs.Fields.Count;"

Comment: I assume that if you go with a forech loop, you will have the same problem. If this is correct, then you probably have to deal with different versions of MS Access. Another test you can do it to use the local access and retrieve data from the remote one.

Comment: if you decide to keep your code move the List<string> b outside the while loop, also loop thru the field names and at the end add them to a string[] array then use the sting.Join method passing a (",") comma as the delim and then do something like strarrayColumnNames = lstColumns.ToArray(); making sure you declare strarrayColumnNames as string[] strarrayColumnNames = {}